# ASPNET MVC5, Files Upload Database, Varbinary

Tags: database, file, asp.net-mvc-5, varbinary

I wish to make an upload of my documents in database.(MVC5, Varbinary)

At first I store these documents in a folder on the server ("ServeurPathFolder/IdUser"), 
and that works perfectly => [image: Screenshot]

Now i wish to save these files in database with the same controller.

=> Withj the Debug mode, I get well In the UploadController but all my parameters are NULL and finally there is a NULL REFERENCE EXCEPTION do you know why ?

```
  public JsonResult Upload(FilesIndexViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase files)
```

[image: MyDatabase]

My ViewModel

```
public class FilesIndexViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }

        public byte ID_TYPE { get; set; }

        public byte ID_CR{ get; set; }

        public string ID_CREATEUR { get; set; }

        public DateTime DT_CREATION { get; set; }

        public string LIB { get; set; }

        public string TEXT { get; set; }

        public string CD_CONTENT_TYPE { get; set; }
    }
```

My view(_Files)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "FileUpload", FormMethod.Post, new { encType = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <form id="fileupload">
        @*<form id="fileupload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-url="@Url.Action("Upload", "FileUpload")">*@
            <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                    <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                    <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                        <span>Add files...</span>
                        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                    </span>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                        <span>Start upload</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                        <span>Cancel upload</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                        <span>Delete</span>
                    </button>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
                    <!-- The global file processing state -->
                    <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- The global progress state -->
                <div class="col-lg-5 fileupload-progress fade">
                    <!-- The global progress bar -->
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- The extended global progress state -->
                    <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- The global progress state -->
            <div class="col-lg-5 fileupload-progress fade">
                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- The extended global progress state -->
                <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>

            <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
            <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
        </form>
```

And my Controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Upload(FilesIndexViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase files)
{
    var uploadedFile = (model.File != null && model.File.ContentLength > 0) ? new byte[model.File.InputStream.Length] : null;
    if (uploadedFile != null)
    {
        model.File.InputStream.Read(uploadedFile, 0, uploadedFile.Length);
    }
    CTG_DOCUMENT image = new CTG_DOCUMENT
    {
        ID_TYPE = model.ID_TYPE,
        ID_CR = model.ID_CR,
        ID_CREATEUR = model.ID_CREATEUR,
        DT_CREATION = DateTime.Now,
        LIB = model.LIB,
        DOCUMENT = uploadedFile,
        CD_CONTENT_TYPE = model.CD_CONTENT_TYPE
    };
    db.CTG_DOCUMENT.Add(image);
    db.SaveChanges();

    var resultList = new List<ViewDataUploadFilesResult>();

    var CurrentContext = HttpContext;

    filesHelper.UploadAndShowResults(CurrentContext, resultList);
    JsonFiles Jfiles = new JsonFiles(resultList);

    bool isEmpty = !resultList.Any();


    if (isEmpty)
    {
        return Json("Error ");
    }
    else
    {              
        return Json(Jfiles);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Your input element to browser files should have the same name attribute value as your action method parameter of type `HttpPostedFileBase`.

So update your razor view code have the input element name as `"files"`

```
<input type="file" name="files" multiple>
```

Also, I see you have multiple attribute on the file input element. If you prefer to send multiple files, you should update your action method parameter to a collection of HttpPostedFileBase.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Upload(FilesIndexViewModel model,IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
  // loop through files after making sure it is not null
}
```

I also noticed that you already have a property in your view model of type HttoPostedFileBase. In that case,you do not need to have the second parameter in your HttpPost action method.

and your action method can be

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Upload(FilesIndexViewModel model)
{
  //check model.File property value
}
```

Also, as i mentioned earlier, if you want to support muliple file uploads, simply change this property of your view model to a collection of `HttpPostedFile`